# My Socket.io on IOS fails to handshake with the websocket server

Tags: ios, node.js, websocket, socket.io, pomelo

I have a Node.js server running Websocket. (using Pomelo).  I am able to run a web application and connect to it (localhost @port 3104).

however, when I try to use socket.io (SocketRocket) for IOS and connect to the same localhost and port, I get this error:

```
> http://127.0.0.1:3014/socket.io/1/?t=16807 
> "ERROR: handshake failed ... The request timed out"
```

detail of the error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x6c723c0 
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:3014/socket.io/1/?t=16807, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:3014/socket.io/1/?t=16807, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x6c72400 "The request timed out."}
```

i tried. 127.0.01, localhost... even explicit IP address.. all fail

any idea what I should check?
and should it be "http" protocol ? or wss?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SocketRocket with socket.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302561/how-to-use-socketrocket-with-socket-io)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.. I just cannot run a websocket server.  I have to run a socket.io server... then it works.

Comment: Hello, can you pls help me in js file. I am getting ERROR: handshake failed ... The request timed out" ervery time. while in browser it wroks file.

Comment: <p>var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3000, function () {  console.log('listening on *:3000');});
var users = {};
app.get('/', function(req, res){  res.sendfile('index.html'); });
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("register", function(username) {
  users[username] = socket.id;
  });
     socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
         io.sockets.emit('new message',msg);
     });
});
</p>